# TextField "Intro" Tap on the keyboard SwiftUI (iOS 14)

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, textfield, ios14

Did you ever try to handle the event when you press `intro` and the `keyboard` dismiss in `SwiftUI` using `TextField`?

```
TextField("type your name here", text: $yourName)
```

How can I know when user `dismiss keyboard` pressing 'intro' button?

**Thank you so much!**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onCommit` parameter from `TextField`. Here is an example:

```
TextField("type your name here", text: $yourName, onCommit: {
    print("return key pressed")
})
```

---

From the documentation:

```
/// [...]
///   - onCommit: An action to perform when the user performs an action
///     (for example, when the user presses the Return key) while the text
///     field has focus.
public init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, text: Binding<String>, onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }, onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = {})
```

Answer (score 1):

After the `TextField` is declared, add a closure and fill it with this code: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)`

So altogether it looks like

```
TextField($yourText){
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
}
```

It is explained in this video around the 8:00 mark.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfJ70vHABjs

Comment: onCommit allow you handle when user press "on return key" and that's what I was looking for... Anyway I really appreciate your answer